# counting the occurence of a particular String in a file

Tags: java, regex, string

Here's the code that I've worked upon:

```
while ((lineContents = tempFileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
            String lineByLine = lineContents.replaceAll("/\\.", System.getProperty("line.separator")); //for matching /. and replacing it by new line
            changer.write(lineByLine);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\r?\\n"); //Find new line
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineByLine);
            while(matcher.find())
            {
                Pattern tagFinder = Pattern.compile("word"); //Finding the word required
                Matcher tagMatcher = tagFinder.matcher(lineByLine);
                while(tagMatcher.find())
                {
                    score++;
                }
                scoreTracker.add(score);
                    score = 0;
            }   
}
```

My sample input contains 6 lines, with occurences of `word` being `[0,1,0,3,0,0]`
So when I print `scoreTracker` (which is an `ArrayList`) I want the above output. 
But instead, I get `[4,4,4,4,4,4]` which it the total occurence of the `word`, but not line by line.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lineByLine` points to the entire contents of your file. That is the reason you are getting `[4,4,4,4,4,4]`. You need to store each line in another variable `line` and then use `tagFinder.find(line)`.
Final code will look like this

```
while ((lineContents = tempFileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    String lineByLine = lineContents.replaceAll("/\\.", System.getProperty("line.separator")); //for matching /. and replacing it by new line
    changer.write(lineByLine);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\r?\\n"); //Find new line
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineByLine);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        Pattern tagFinder = Pattern.compile("word"); //Finding the word required
        //matcher.group() returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.
        Matcher tagMatcher = tagFinder.matcher(matcher.group());
        while(tagMatcher.find())
        {
            score++;
        }
        scoreTracker.add(score);
            score = 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: But that is the reason why I'm finding a new line first in my `String` and then applying to the result my score. The `while` loop for `matcher` ? Am I wrong with that?

Comment: @KazekageGaara There are two issues in your code. One is that the first regex `pattern` is for finding a new line delimiter. It does not capture the line itself. So you need to change the regex to `(.*)\\r?\\n`. Secondly you are invoking `matcher.find()` and you are not calling `matcher.group()` anywhere to extract the match. Make these two changes and it should be fine. More info about `Matcher` object here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will help you:

```
    String str = "word word\n \n word word\n \n word\n";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\r?\\n"); //Find new line
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        Pattern tagFinder = Pattern.compile("word"); //Finding the word required
        Matcher tagMatcher = tagFinder.matcher(matcher.group());
        int score = 0;
        while(tagMatcher.find())
        {
            score++;
        }
        System.out.print(score + " ");
    }
```

The output is `2 0 2 0 1` It is not highly optimized, but your problem was that you never restricted the inner matching and it always scanned the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

This is because each time you are searching the same string (lineByLine). what you probably intended was to search each line separately. I suggest you do:

```
    Pattern tagFinder = Pattern.compile("word"); //Finding the word required
    for(String line : lineByLine.split("\\n")
    {
        Matcher tagMatcher = tagFinder.matcher(line);
        while(tagMatcher.find())
            score++;
        scoreTracker.add(score);
        score = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The original code was reading the input one line at a time using `tempFileReader.readLine()` and then looking for end of lines within each line using `matcher`. Since `lineContents` contains only one line, `matcher` never finds a new line so the rest of the code is skipped.
Why do you need two different bits of code to split the input into lines?
You could remove one of the bits of code relating to finding the new lines. E.g.

```
while ((lineContents = tempFileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
      Pattern tagFinder = Pattern.compile("word"); //Finding the word required
      Matcher tagMatcher = tagFinder.matcher(lineContents);
      while(tagMatcher.find())
      {
          score++;
      }
      scoreTracker.add(score);
      score = 0;

}
```

I've tried the code above using a file test.txt on Windows read by a `BufferedReader`. E.g.

```
BufferedReader tempFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\test\\test.txt"));
```

scoreTracker contains [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0] for a file which has the content you describe.
I don't understand how you got [4,4,4,4,4,4] out of the original code if the sample input is an actual file as described and `tempFileReader` is a `BufferedReader`. It would be useful to see the code you use to set up `tempFileReader`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner class. You initialize the Scanner to the string you want to count and then just count how many these tokens Scanner finds.

And you can initialize Scanner directly with the FileInputStream.

The resulting code has only 9 lines:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
scanner.useDelimiter("your text here");
int occurences;
while(scanner.hasNext()){
     scanner.next();
     occurences++;
}
scanner.close();
```