# Count number of times string appears in a file

Tags: java, search, filereader, java-io

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain string appears in a text file (.txt), and so far, I got FileReader to work (it reads the file, and I can output the text in the file to the console). What I'm trying to do know is check if a string (inputted by a user) exists in the text file. What I have so far is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {

    String fileName = "test.txt";
    String line = null;
    int counter = 0;

    public String getUserInput() {
        String userInput;
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = userInputScanner.nextLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    public String returnUserInput() {
        String userInput = getUserInput();
        return userInput;
    }


    public void readFile() {        
        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                while (line.indexOf(word, indexOfWord) != -1) {
                    indexOfWord += word.length();
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Assignment2 test = new Assignment2();
        test.readFile();
    }

}
```

Whats happening is that I can't loop through the file, and when I run the program with the for loop, it gets stuck(?), it just keeps running with no errors, but it does nothing.

I know that my problem is with the for loop (line.length() won't work, because the buffered reader reads one line at a time... what I really want is to get the number of strings in the file). I'm also having trouble checking user input (I want to ignore the case of the letters, but I cannot do that with .contains(), and I can't think of another way to check if the line contains the user input).

Also, is my though process correct, or is the way I'm doing this not efficient? I have to check a 3000 word document.

Comment: What is your question?  What is the problem?  Please edit your question to include the exact error and exact intended behavior.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me. You should not ask such questions directly here. If it's only 3000 words, you may simply read the whole file into memory and concatenate lines (StringBuilder), then count the number of occurrences with a for loop.

Comment: If you're looking for other approaches, you can search SO for other questions about [counting the occurence of a particular String in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689860/counting-the-occurence-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not "stuck", it is waiting for you to enter the "user input" (again).

You keep calling `returnUserInput()` inside the loop, and it calls `getUserInput()`, which will wait for you to type (another) string and press Enter.

---

As for your code, don't declare `line` as a field. It should be a local variable.

For repeatedly searching for text in a line, don't use `contains()` or a loop of every character of the line. Use [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

**Update**

The code should be like this:

```
String word = returnUserInput();
this.counter = 0;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        for (int i = 0; (i = line.indexOf(word, i)) != -1; i += word.length()) {
            this.counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So line should be declared in the readFile function? And for using indexOf, that just returns the first time the string is found. Is there a way to repeat it, and every time it returns an index, I can increment a counter?

Comment: @MahmudAssamaray Yes, inside method. --- You keep calling `indexOf()` with a `fromIndex` equal to returned value of previous call plus length of search string. On first call, `fromIndex` should be `0`.

Comment: I almost got it working... but for some reason when I input a word that exists in the file it returns a number larger than the number of occurrences. This is the code that I added `while (line.indexOf(word, indexOfWord) != -1) {
     indexOfWord += word.length();
     counter += 1;
    }` I'll also update my question to show the new code, for readability

Comment: That always returns 1, if the string exists, as in, when I do system.out.println(counter);. it outputs 1. I did it another way, I loop through and truncate the text file, its working that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore case use the following method:

```
line.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
```

line is the line you read from file.

text is the string user inputed which is what you are looking for.

define a counter variable to keep track of numbers.

Afterwards check if a match was found, and if so increment the counter.
I can give you the exact code, but then you will not learn. If you get stuck and this doesn't work, I can help you further.